# Using django SessionStore without knowing key

Tags: django, django-sessions

I'm writing a django app that requires an object to be somewhat persistent, at least for the purposes of a session. It is not view-based, so I'm looking at SessionStore as the place to create, then retrieve it from. However, SessionStore requires a session_key in order to retrieve the object. My app need to use this persistent object from the save() method of certain models, so I can't pass the session_id to the save() function in all cases (e.g. when a model instance is created via the admin site). Is it possible to access the 'current session' somehow in django, without using either the request object, or knowing the session_key?

Comment: Inspect the SessionStorage.

Comment: @dan-klasson - what do I do with it/where do I get it from? The constructor requires a request object, which I don't want to pass around everywhere. Or is there a persistent SessionStorage I can access from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If your primary hurdle is lack of access to the request object when saving in the admin site, review how to use [ModelAdmin.save_model(self, request, obj, form, change)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).